# htmlentities() is not working in php form

Tags: php, html

htmlentities is not wroking, it should escape quotes but is does not.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id( true );
if(isset($_REQUEST['sub'])){
    echo $name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email'] );
    echo $pswd = $_REQUEST['pswd'];
    echo $abc = htmlentities($pswd ,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    //echo $pswd = htmlentities("hello" ,ENT_QUOTES);   
}
?>


<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Login form</h2>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd" required>
    </div>    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sub">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see 1 line is comment, If I pass a value with quotes in htmlentites(), It outputs the value without quotes, But If I am passing a value from my form, suppose I passed "hello". " " are included. And store this value in php variable and then pass this variable in htmlentites(). It shows output in "", But it should ignore quotes.

Comment: echo $pswd = $_REQUEST['pswd'];
    echo $abc = htmlentities($pswd ,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");check these two lines, I have all ready done that

Comment: and that works?

Comment: No that did not works@xmastertje

Comment: | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8" this solutions also failed@xmastertje

Comment: can you `var_dump` your  `$_REQUEST['pswd']`

Comment: what does it say?

Comment: Where did you check that? In the raw markup or in your browser? Can you provide the minimal parts of code to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is difference in how you are using the both htmlentities function. If you want to imitate how the first one will work, the one that is commented out should look like this:

`htmlentities('"hello"' ,ENT_QUOTES);`

In your example in the commented out function call, the quotes serve as part of the  function, you are passing a parameter like that, so they never even get to be parsed by the function.

The purpose of the htmlentities is not to strip away characters, but to escape them, so you will never see a sign missing. The use of html entities is for example to print a string in the html like `<p>`. If not passed through htmlentities it will render a html **p** tag, if passed through htmlentities like `htmlentities('<p>')` it will print exaclty that string.